# Connect to AS400 via PHP - Which adapter - performance?

Tags: php, performance, ibm-midrange

Next month I need to develop a script to connect to an AS400 and query some data (>1000000). I want to do this with PHP, as I am doing a lot with PHP.

My question know is, how should I connect to the As400. I know that there is ODBC, but everyone said to me ODBC is sub-optimal because it cannot handle large dataset with a great performance. Everyone recommends me JDBC.

So what do you recommend me. What would you use if you get this task... I do not plan to switch the programming language if it is not as must.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about performance on ODBC and if there are differences based on the platform you are running it against, but I believe ODBC is the only way you can connect to the i with PHP if you are using PHP on a remote server. I do know that the i can handle large amounts of data much better than most other SQL database servers.

You could also ask this question on [Web400](http://murl.me/web400) at Midrange.com. There are several on that list that use PHP and there are even a couple of people from Zend on the list that could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

The IBM i (current name of platform) has database drivers for .NET and Java.

It *may* be that the DB2 universal driver for your platform can connect to the system, but I do not have personal experience with that.